# Drupal, ImageCache module not scaling properly

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've set on imagecache a fixed scale for my images (230 x 150).
Upscaling option is unchecked.

Successively, I've uploaded new images (original size 230 x 150) but for some reason they are resized: 80 x 52

Instead, if I check the "Allow upscaling" option, the size is correct, but the quality is very bad.

So basically, it behaves like if my images are very small, but my original images have the correct size.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect of the 'allow upscaling' option hints on the problem not being caused by imagecache itself, but rather that some other setting/module is downscaling the images already *before* imagecache is doing its thing. You could try to verify this by checking the image sizes of the originally uploaded images (usually in 'files/images' or somewhere else *outside* of 'files/imagecache').

What mechanism/module do you use to upload the images? (There might be a scaling setting somewhere in that context.)